# Symfony2 logging not working in production

Tags: php, symfony, logging

In my symfony application when looking at the app/logs directory its completely empty and nothing seems to be logging on production however on my dev environment it works just fine.

in my /web/app.php file i have

```
$environments = array(
   'dev.url.com'         => 'dev',
   'produ.url.com'       => 'prod'
);
```

when looking at the /app/logs directory the folder is completely empty there isnt even a prod.log file however if i go into my /web/app.php file and change the value from prod to dev on the same server it starts to log everything just fine.

I do have a /app/config/config_prod.yml and a config_dev.yml

I cant figure out if there is a setting somewhere that is blocking this from working when the environment is set to prod? I have all the correct permissions on the directories as well too.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions can often be the issue here - make sure write permissions are granted for both the web server (or PHP user - depending on your setup) - plus make sure if you have been running any console scripts from the commandline - then make sure that user can write too.

Also ensure that the cache directory has write enabled too.

There are additional setup hints in the great Symfony documentation.

Comment: The permissions are all correct. Its just weird that if i go onto the server and change the produ.url.com from prod to dev it starts to work.